# How to convert string of hex to hex in C?

Tags: c, char, hex

I trying to convert string of hex to hex in C.

Example: "FF"(char type) to hex FF(int type).

Does it possible ? How can I do that ?

Comment: You want [`strtol()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) with radix as 16

Comment: Thank you very much for keyword. I'm going to try.

Comment: Yes, this is also working. I think I had been made a duplication.